# Equivalency of two forms of Lebesgue measurability

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Following is the Carathéodory's criterion for Lebesgue measurability

> $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable $\textbf{iff}$ for any set B (measurable or not) $m_*(B)=m_*(B\cap A)+m_*(B -A)$.

where $m_*(B)$ is the outer measure of $A$.

How one could show that this is equivalent to other criteria of Lebesgue measurability such as

> $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable $\textbf{iff}$ for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists an open set $O$ that contains $A$ and $m_*(O-A)<\epsilon$.

The above criterion can be found in Stein Shakarchi "Real Analysis" book printed 2007, page 21, Theorem 3.4.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but isn't this definition of Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @Ennar I don't think so. In my last paragraph I used one of the definitions to prove, but not successful yet.

Comment: Well, how do you define Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @Ennar I see what you are talking about. The one I mentioned above is the definition of Lebesgue measure in Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure. But my definition is that if A is Lebesgue measurable then for every positive ε there exist an open set G and a closed set F such that G⊇A⊇F and λ(G\A)<ε and λ(A\F)<ε.

Comment: What you state is regularity of Lebesgue measure. [See.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularity_theorem_for_Lebesgue_measure) I'm not aware of characterization of Lebesgue measure via regularity alone. Where is this definition from?

Comment: @Ennar Property 10 in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure . You can also see that in Stein Shakarchi book "real analysis" page  21 Theorem 3.4.

Comment: You should include this definition in your question because, as far as I know, standard approach is through Caratheodory construction described in Wikipedia, and the definition you are using is proved as a theorem. The current form of question might be confusing to others as it was to me.

Comment: @Ennar Thanks. I added that to the problem statement.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305221/equivalent-definitions-of-lebesgue-measurability